# Porque existe prazo para oferecer recompensa a resposta já existente

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica, recompensa

Agora fui conceder uma recompensa [numa reposta já existente numa pergunta de outro usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71094/m%C3%A1scara-em-js-para-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-horas) (já está até aceita), e achei que pelo sistema perguntar se a recompensa era para uma resposta já existente (e eu responder que sim), que já iria aparecer a opção de escolher qual a resposta.

Mas não, ele só abriu a recompensa normalmente, e está exigindo 24 horas de prazo pra que eu possa conceder a recompensa.

Faz sentido isso?

Comment: Sua visão faz sentido, mas acredito que seja pra dar "mais opções" de melhores respostas

Comment: Mas quando é pra uma resposta específica, ainda mais se já está aceita, acho que não faz sentido a espera. (btw, daria fácil mais 50 pela versão custom do @Sergio :-)).

Comment: De fato, ele disse que estava trabalhando nela desde ontem, ainda acharia válido ele postar como resposta.

Comment: Muito, a solução que vc postou já resolveu pra mim, mas como não roda na versão mais atual do plugin, e precisa de 3 arquivos externos, seria muito legal se ele postasse quando ficar pronto.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Na minha opinião, faz todo o sentido: parte do objetivo do sistema de recompensas é, bem, "recompensar" o usuário (dando-lhe pontos de reputação). Mas a outra parte é chamar a atenção para perguntas e também para boas respostas. Esse período de 24h dá a chance de outras pessoas verem o conteúdo avaliado como "excepcional", e não apenas votar no mesmo mas principalmente se beneficiar também do conhecimento contido ali.

Essa visibilidade adicional permite inclusive maior escrutínio sobre o conteúdo postado. Ok, a resposta era boa e foi aceita, mas será que ela não pode ser melhorada? Será que não existem respostas melhores, ainda que a recompensa acabe indo mesmo pra resposta original? (responder perguntas com recompensa é bom não só pela possibilidade de ganhar a recompensa, mas também pelos votos de outros usuários que estiverem vendo a mesma pergunta) Será que *a pergunta em si* não se beneficiaria de uma boa revisão, talvez melhorando o título e o texto de modo a ser mais útil pra outros usuários no futuro? Etc.

Seria "catastrófico" se não houvesse esse período de espera? Não, é claro: os outros usuários ainda poderiam encontrar aquela resposta numa busca, ou navegando pelo site. Mas haja vista que há algum benefício em se ter a espera, e seria custoso não tê-la (pois precisaria de código especial para tratar de um único item na lista de "motivos", itens que fora o texto não são diferentes em sua natureza), creio que seria melhor manter tudo como está.

Comment: Ainda não tinha pensado pelo lado da exposição. Quando concedo a recompensa ela deixa de ficar em destaque né...+1